# Как вывести два случайных не повторяющихся числа в СИ?

Tags: c, случайные-числа

Как вывести два случайных не повторяющихся числа в СИ в диапазоне от 0 до 10?

```
 srand(time(NULL));
 int a = rand()%9;
 int b = rand()%9;
```

Здесь числа случайные, но могут повторяться

Comment: `while((b = rand()%9)==a);`

Answer (score 4):

Генерим первое, любое случайное от 0 до 9.
Генерим дополнительное случайное от 1 до 9.
Считаем второе случайное как сумма первого и дополнительного по модулю 10. Получаем также число от 0 до 9, причём гарантированно не равное первому случайному.

Т.е. приблизительно (в сях не силён)

```
int a = rand()%9; 
int b = (a + 1 + rand()%8)%9;
```

Answer (score 4):

```
int a = rand()%11; // 0 .. 10
int b = (a + 1 + rand()%10)%11; // 0 .. a - 1 , a + 1 .. 10
```

Answer (score 3):

Поскольку исправлять предыдущего оратора не хочтся...

```
int a = rand()%9, b;
while((b = rand()%9)==a);
```

Answer (score 2):

Если не использовать какую-нибудь функцию, которая сама так умеет, то просто проверять а и b на равенство:

```
int b = rand()%9;

int a = rand()%9;
while (a == b) {
    b = rand()%9;
}
```

Comment: @Harry опередил с правкой на две секунды! Причем == я еще успел сохранить, а удалить int уже не успел :)

Comment: Да сам принцип неверен. Получается, что цикл закончится, когда `a` и `b` одинаковы. Тут уж я не берусь править...

Comment: @Harry да я же уже поменял, оно опять вернулось.

Comment: Нет, `b` надо делать не `-1`. Вобщем, извините, я больше не лезу с правками...

Answer (score 0):

Длинный вариант:

```
const int SIZE = 2;
int arr[SIZE];

int alreadyThere;

for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; )
{
alreadyThere = 0;
int newRanomValue = rand() % 10;

for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
{
if (arr[j]==newRanomValue)
{
alreadyThere = 1;
break;
}
}

if (!alreadyThere)
{
arr[i] = newRanomValue;
i++;
}

}

for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
{
  printf([i]);
}
```